# How to effectively (inplace) multiply two views of memmaped numpy arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra, vectorization

Imagine, I have

```
a = np.memmap(..)
b = np.memmap(..)
```

I'd like to get element wise result and a updated.

```
a = a[0:size1:2] * b[1:size1:3]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ankur, I'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a[0:size1:2]` and `b[1:size1:3]` are the same dimension (or at least broadcastable), you can use the fact that slices of numpy arrays share memory:

```
temp_a = a[0:size1:2]
temp_a *= b[1:size1:3]
```

This will update only the values of `a` that are in `temp_a`.